# Need to generate numbers randomly with each value as equal number of times from a given list of numbers using any java API

Tags: java, random

Random.nextInt(int n) method is generating numbers randomly with equal number of chances for each number from the given range. But i need to get output numbers with equal number of times from given range 0-5
Ex: n=5;

```
For (int i=0; i<10;i++) {
Syso(random.nextInt(n));
}
```

Giving output
Each number randomly between 0-n but i need  output such like each number should come twice as loop is happening for 10 times even the generation is random like 2,4,1,3,5,1,5,4,2,3

Is there any java api to achieve this or any logic would help me.

Answer (score 1):

First make a list of the numbers you want: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5].  Then shuffle the list into a random order.

Looking at your question, you do not want random numbers; you want a fixed set of numbers in random order.  Hence a shuffle is what you need.

Comment: The thing is i want to distribute list of numbers uniformly to another list of users. I made it through custom logic like maintaining the assignment count of each number from the first list some where for reference. Thanks